# Linked Server COMMIT TRANSACTION fail on TRY CATCH

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

i'm working with Linked Server, and this code working fine

```
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO [Dev].[dbo].tb_test (no)  SELECT no from [MYLINKEDSERVER].[mydb].[dbo].tb_test 
    DELETE FROM [MYLINKEDSERVER].[mydb].[dbo].tb_test
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 'fail'
END CATCH
```

but when i use it with COMMIT TRANSACTION, like this

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    INSERT INTO [Dev].[dbo].tb_test (no)  SELECT no from [MYLINKEDSERVER].[mydb].[dbo].tb_test 
    DELETE FROM [MYLINKEDSERVER].[mydb].[dbo].tb_test
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

show error

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "MYLINKEDSERVER" returned message
>   "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for
>   remote/network transactions.".

What is wrong?

Comment: Are you looking for this ? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/24d74b4f-cf65-4b1b-8ba6-e87c1858b710/linked-server-the-partner-transaction-manager-has-disabled-its-support-for-remotenetwork?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: @Aditya i've tried, and still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to write a stored procedure on remote server with return value, and execute it locally:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    INSERT INTO [Dev].[dbo].tb_test (no)  
        SELECT no 
        FROM [MYLINKEDSERVER].[mydb].[dbo].tb_test 

    DECLARE @returnvalue INT

    EXEC @returnvalue = [MYLINKEDSERVER].[mydb].[dbo].sp_update @no

    IF @returnvalue = 1
    BEGIN
        COMMIT
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

The stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_update] 
     @no NVARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            DELETE FROM mytb 
            WHERE no = @no

            COMMIT
            RETURN 1
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK
        RETURN 0
    END CATCH
END
```

Hope help someone

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

Try executing below command on Server on which you are going to do insert operation.

```
EXEC sp_serveroption @server = 'ReadServerName',@optname = 'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue = 'false' ;
```

Also try executing below code. I have added `BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION` instead of `BEGIN TRANSACTION`.

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO [Dev].[dbo].tb_test (no)  SELECT no from [MYLINKEDSERVER].[mydb].[dbo].tb_test 
    DELETE FROM [MYLINKEDSERVER].[mydb].[dbo].tb_test
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

Details are available at [MS site](http://%20https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/24d74b4f-cf65-4b1b-8ba6-e87c1858b710/linked-server-the-partner-transaction-manager-has-disabled-its-support-for-remotenetwork?forum=sqldatabaseengine).

Comment: Have you have set the allow remote transactions on both sides ?

Comment: @MahdiArahman, try INS-SEL query by removing the try catch block as well.

Comment: my procedure working fine without COMMIT TRANSACTION, 
is COMMIT TRANSACTION not working on linkedserver?

Comment: INS-SEL query working fine on local db, but not on linkedserver

Comment: Try using "BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION <<your SQL>> COMMIT TRANSACTION".

Comment: BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION also fail

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work

```
DECLARE @ServerName SYSNAME
, @Message nvarchar(1000)
, @CMD1 nvarchar(max)
--
DECLARE @Server_List Table
( SrvID SMALLINT
, SrvName SYSNAME )
--
Set NoCount ON
--
-- Load up linked server list
--
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Server_List (SrvID, SrvName)
SELECT SrvID
, SrvName 
FROM [master].[SYS].sysservers
ORDER BY SrvID ASC
END
--
SELECT TOP 1 @ServerName = SrvName
FROM @Server_List
ORDER BY SrvID ASC
--
-- Loop through the Linked Server List
--
WHILE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM @Server_List )
BEGIN
SELECT @Message = 'Server Name is '+ @ServerName
--
RAISERROR (@Message, 10,1) WITH NOWAIT
--
SET @CMD1 = 'EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'''
+ @ServerName
+ ''', @optname=N''rpc'', @optvalue=N''true'''
Exec sp_executesql @cmd1
--
SET @CMD1 = 'EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'''
+ @ServerName
+ ''', @optname=N''rpc out'', @optvalue=N''true'''
Exec sp_executesql @cmd1
--
set @cmd1 = 'EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server = '''
+ @ServerName
+ ''', @optname=N''remote proc transaction promotion'', @optvalue=N''false'''
Exec sp_executesql @stmt=@cmd1,@params=N''
--
DELETE FROM @Server_List WHERE SrvName = @ServerName
--
SELECT TOP 1 @ServerName = SrvName
FROM @Server_List
ORDER BY SrvID ASC
--
END
```